# Объект как свойство объекта в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, json

Такая ситуация:

1. Есть база данных на сервере, реализованном на Java.
2. Есть объекты `Customer` и `Photo`.
3. Каждому `Customer` соответствует `Photo`.

Как это правильно реализовать в JavaScript для десериализации из JSON?
Нужно ли каждому `Customer` добавлять свойство `Photo` и `Customer` свойство `Photo`?

Comment: То есть "нужно ли на клиенте полностью воспроизводить схему данных сервера со всеми связами?". Обычно нет, не нужно. Вообще в таком виде задача малопонятна. Попробуйте сформулировать свою проблему каким-то естественным языком или наглядным примером.

Comment: Спасибо, что откликнулись. Сейчас попытаюсь...Можно в чате?

Comment: Попробуйте, доступ есть? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43051/

Comment: Не работает) В целом, вы мой вопрос поняли правильно...У пользователя есть поля-объекты из БД. Пока не добавляю их в БД все работает, как только добавляю JS перестает общаться с сервером. Я так понимаю, что неправильно десереализуется. Я только начал недавно с JS разбираться, поэтому не судите строго) Ткните на ссылку где почитать, если несложно)

Comment: Я плюсанул вопрос и теперь у вас вроде достаточно репы для чатов чтобы мне не пришлось разбираться почему не работает доступ ручками. Попробуйте написать там еще раз

Comment: Так, перво наперво давайте проблему уточним. Вы пытаетесь ее обобщить, в результате выходит странно и непонятно. Начнем не с архитектурной задачи а с конкретной. При добавлении какой-то сущности в бд она перестает правильно десериализовываться на клиенте, я правильно понял?

Comment: Как я понял, мне надо не Customer пересылать со всеми  сущьностями,а Data, в котором и Customer, и Photo, и все остальное, но как отдельные объекты?

Comment: Вам надо пересылать на клиент то что нужно на клиенте. И то что логично пересылать по соответствующим запросам к серверному API.

На запрос фото надо пересылать фото, на запрос данных юзера - пересылать данные юзера. На запрос "ДАЙ МНЕ ВСЕ" - пересылать все. Но запроса "дай мне все" в теории быть не должно. Можно ли один объект сразу пересылать свойством другого? - да можно. Говорю же, проблема не вполне понятна, и я далеко не уверен что Вы решаете то, что вам надо решить)

Comment: Нужно понимать, что "записи в бд", "структура данных на бэке" и "структура данных на клиенте" - это вообще говоря независимые сущности. И хоть они и имеют много общего, быть абсолютно подобными они не обязаны

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43054/discussion-between---and-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не нужно.

**1.**
*База данных со временем вырастет, и на клиент её всю передать уже не получится не только за приемлемое время и вообще может не получится.*

**2.**
*Вы не уточнили что у вас за база данных. Если MongoDB, то там сама выстроенная структура данных уже решила ваш вопрос. Если какая-нибудь SQL, то см. пункт 3.*

**3.**
*Если связь `один-к-одному`, то её достаточно заменить вложением объекта: `Customer` вложить `Photo`, либо наоборот - тут зависит от того от каких данных выполняется запрос (<sub>нужно конкретизировать вопрос</sub>).*

**4.**
*Наверняка вам нужно данные вытаскивать либо по `Customer`, либо `Photo`. Если вы строите какую-нибудь сводную таблицу, то см. пункт 3. Если у вас форма с полями зависимыми одни от других - то, это несколько запросов к серверу за цепочке зависимостей полей (например если выбрали конкретного `Customer`, то побежали достали только его `Photo`, и что там ещё нужно для других зависящих от него полей).*

**ЗЫ**
Ответ расплывчатый конечно, но и вопрос у вас то же не конкретный...

Comment: Я почти получил ответ на вопрос...SQL-база. Т.е. если я правильно понял, то в моем объкте Data, который я использую для пересылки должен быть и Customer и Photo, как отдельные объекты и я их передаю, в зависимости, от надобности.

Comment: @НиколайЕгоров, я серьезно подозреваю что у вас то, что на английском стеке называется ху-проблем. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem
Это когда пытаешься решить не реальную проблему, которая есть, а проблему которую придумал по ходу, в надежде решить ту, которая есть.

Comment: Почти. Как правило записи БД пересылать на клиент не нужно - достаточно конкретных данных. Например, при запросе пользователей с их аваторками достаточно преслать `{ userId: 1, nick: "User2016", name:"Виктор", avator: "images/pic38547593.jpg" }` где все свойства взяты из таблицы `users` (но при этом свойств в записи таблицы больше, просто в данном запросе они не нужны), кроме свойства `avator` которое досталось из связанной таблицы `photos` (причем из всех свойств таблицы было взято, например, только путь к миниатюре).

Comment: Уточняю, как могу) Есть класс Data, в нем Customer и Message, в Message несколько полей, но с ним все ОК. В свою очередь у Customer есть поля обычные и поля сущьности из БД. Одно их них Photo. Пока я работаю только с полями-несущьностями все работает (отпраляю Data, как JSON  и получаю ответ как JSON), но, как только я добавляю Photo заказчику - от клиента на xmlhttprequest на сервер, ничего не приходит, ну и, соответственно, в клиент не возвращается. На клиенте сделал так: Customer{Photo},Photo{Customer}

Comment: Вообще, советую в начале разобраться реляционными базами данных. В частности нормальными формами. А так же принципами запросов SQL к связанными таблицам. Судя по всему, у вас проблема скорее в первую очередь в понимании принципов работы с базами данных...

Comment: Думаю, вам стоит нарисовать хотя бы примерную схему вашей БД, схему данных на клиенте и ваши запросы к БД за данными необходимыми на клиенте. Прикрепить полученное изображение к вопросу, а лучше задать новый. Тогда, если сами не поймете в чем пробелема, то вам уже конкретно укажут на узкие места.

Comment: А мне кажется что тут проблема не в обращении к бд, а в непонимании как картинку по сети гонять) В общем нужно тщательно допрашивать в чате, с пыточными инструментами

Comment: @t1nk не, проблема в том, как это реализовать правильно в JavaScript. В него я только недавно начал вникать) Суть ответа я понял....Нужно не весь объект со всеми связями отсылать. Типа: Data{Customer,Message,Photo.....}, и уже сюда вкладывать конкретные объетны по надобности. Так? Т.е. передаю от клиента на сервер данные пользователя, а назад просто его фотку?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, если кому интересно. Проблема была в цикличносте полей(и у пользователя есть фото, и у фото есть пользователь). Проблему решил использованием библиотеки Gson(google) и аннотация @Expose(serialize = false/true,deserialize = false/true). Вот отличная статья http://websystique.com/java/json/gson-json-annotations-example/ Всем спасибо, за помощь.